# I'm looking for a delete confirm dialog for my express app

Tags: jquery, express, swig

I'm trying to do this with JQuery. Below is my code. I have a form, with the id "delete". I would like a dialog to appear when a person hits the delete button confirming if this is what they would like to do. If they confirm, the default action happens, if they say no or x out of the dialog, i would like nothing to happen. Right now it the dialog box doesn't appear at all. Have any ideas?

```
 <form action="/delete/{{card.id}}" method="POST" id="delete">
          <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right">
              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></p>
          </button>
        </form>
        <form action="/edit/{{card.id}}" method="POST">
          <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right">
              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></p>
          </button>
        </form>

      </div>
      <hr>
      {{card.content}}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
  $("#delete").submit(function() {
    return var confirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
  });
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

HTML:

```
<a href='#' class='delete' id='35'>Delete data</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    var id = (this).attr("id");
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        // do delete; use var id to delete data
    }
});
```

Instructions in the `if` block will be executed if user will press `ok` button. If he will press `cancel` button nothing will be happened.

In `if` block you can make an ajax-request to the php-script in which you will delete some data. Note, that you have to specify what data you want to delete.